# ngResource appends POST parameters to url

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have an angular service that looks like this. Here i am making a POST request.

```
.factory("Apples", function ($resource, HOST) {

            return $resource(
                HOST + "/apples",
                {},
                {
                    create: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        params: {
                            tree_id: '@treeId',
                            name: '@name',
                            color: '@color'
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        })
```

The problem is that the above service makes a POST request and sends the `params` data as form data but also appends the `params` data to the url as query string. Can i avoid that?

Comment: why do not use `$http` post?

Comment: @MaximShoustin `$resouce` is an abstraction _on top_ of `$http` for making REST easier and returning a uniform querying (and action) REST interface.

Comment: If you don't want the params in the URL, don't configure them as url parameters.  $resource will send the instance data as is (so your data will be `treeId`, not `tree_id`.

Comment: @KevinStone So should i omit `params`? If yes then where do i specify the form data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're conflicted on how to use `$resource`.  You should create $resource instances as if they were models and set the attributes on the object that you want to POST.

With your `Apples` $resource defined as above:

```
var apple = new Apples();

apple.color = ...
apple.name = ...
apple.tree_id = ...

apple.$create()
```

Or you could just use the $resource class directly:

```
Apples.create({
    apple.color: ...
    apple.name: ...
    apple.tree_id: ...
});
```

Finally, $resource has the built-in `$save()` that uses POST which you can use instead of creating a custom `$create()` action.